# Unable to login to Ubuntu 20.04 VMWare Workstation

Tags: 20.04, login-screen

I upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 VMware Workstation, after restarting, I was not able to login.

[image: Click to see image]

When I type password, a black screen appears and then back to the screen in picture.

Comment: I would try to login into X.Org session with clicking on the gear icon in the bottom right corner and selecting "Ubuntu on XOrg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I deleted my virtual machine and contiki os. Reinstalled them, and now they are working fine.